# apt-get symbol lookup error

Tags: apt, package-management

As of recently, I've been getting this error from apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install *something*`

output:
`apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _ZN11CommandLine10GetCommandEPKNS_8DispatchEjPKPKc`

Also apt-add-repository is getting: `sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found`

I've been trying to fix this for days and nothing seems to work for me, as most of the solutions I've found require me to use apt-get, which I obviously can't. Also something else I should mention, is that for some reason I don't have a `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, only a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Is there maybe any place I can manually download apt-get without using apt-get and reinstall it?

Using Ubuntu 16.04

edit:

`apt-cache policy libapt-pkg5.0` gets the same error as `apt-get` above.

and `dpkg -C` gives me:

`The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 apt                  commandline package manager`

edit-2:

`sudo dpkg --configure apt` gets:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.16); however:
  Version of libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 on system is 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21.
 libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.2.15) breaks apt (<< 1.1~exp14) and is installed.
  Version of apt to be configured is 1.0.1ubuntu2.17.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and check the boxes on the repos. It will create the `sources.list`.

Comment: But something is wrong with your system.

Comment: @Pilot6 In 'System Settings' I don't have a 'Softare & Updates' button, which is odd because I'm pretty sure I've used that before on this machine.

Comment: Please add outputs of `apt-cache policy libapt-pkg5.0` and `dpkg -C libapt-pkg5.0`

Comment: @steeldriver edited post

Comment: Well I guess `sudo dpkg --configure apt` is worth a (long)shot - beyond that you are likely right, you will need to re-install the broken packages manually (hopefully `dpkg` is not broken as well).

Comment: @steeldriver post edited. So how can I go about reinstalling everything manually?

Comment: Hmm... quite a pickle - let's think about that

Comment: I guess before trying to fix this manually, we need to figure out how such old / incompatible versions of `apt` and its dependent packages are on your system - did you have a release upgrade that went bad? or have outdated PPAs in your sources?

Comment: @steeldriver Honestly I'm not entirely sure. Not sure if it does any good but a while back I had some issues installing Google Chrome, and there were some dependencies I was missing that I installed manually but I never got Chrome to work after that. I never really tried using apt-get since then until recently so I never saw that it was broken. I'm honestly not really sure what I did to make this happen, as I've just been going about my day normally on this computer without needing to use apt-get for a while.

Comment: Also I first installed Ubuntu on this machine when it was on 14.04.4 and I've upgraded to 16.04 since. But I don't believe anything went wrong after that.